# $|X_k| \leq Y \in L^1,$ if $X_k \Rightarrow X$ then $E[X_k|\mathcal{F}] \Rightarrow E[X|\mathcal{F}]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Consider on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{W},P),$ a sequence $(X_k)_k$ of random variable such that $|X_k| \leq Y \in L^1,$ consider a sub $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}.$

- If $X_k$ **converges a.s** to $X$ then $E[X_k|\mathcal{F}]$ **converges a.s** to $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$
- If $X_k$ **converges in probability** to $X$ then $E[X_k|\mathcal{F}]$ **converges in probability** to $E[X|\mathcal{F}].$

Does this hold for weak convergence? In other word, is it true that if $X_k$ **converges in distributio**n to $X$ then $E[X_k|\mathcal{F}]$ **converges in distribution** to $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X, X_k$ be independent non-constant random variables drawn from the same distribution and let $\mathcal{F} = \sigma (X)$. Then $X_k$ converge in distribution to $X$; also, $E[X | \sigma (X)] = X$, but, by independence, $E[X_k | \sigma (X)] = E[X_k]$, which is a constant.